# Subfolder routing not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble in routing my files. I need to access the `new_account` subfolder and the controllers inside it...

Here is the structure:

```
controllers
---new_account
---------step1.php
---------step2.php
---accounts.php 
---pages.php
```

This is the content of my `.htaccess` file located outside `application`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And here is my `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/show_page/home';
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/show_page/$1';
$route['accounts'] = 'accounts';
$route['new_account/(:any)'] = "new_account";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/show_page/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I also use `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

My `pages` controller is working perfectly, even as direct links e.g. `<?php echo base_url(); ?>home` redirects to `../pages/home.php`.

The `accounts.php` controller calls `new_account/user_home.php` that contains guidelines and a link to the actual form. The link is `<?php base_url();>new_account/step1` and it does not work which should have because of `$route['new_account/(:any)'] = "new_account";`.

Whenever I click the link to `new_account/step1`, I get redirected to the main home page.

I really want to access `app_name/new_account/step1` and the others in the directory...Did I miss something in these files or an integral step?

NOTE:

I also tried [this subfolder routing extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213115/route-to-multiple-sub-folders-in-codeigniter) by inserting `MY_Router.php` in the `application/libraries` folder but no changes happened. I then moved it into `application/core` but all I get is a server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment this line in your `routes.php`:

```
$route['new_account/(:any)'] = "new_account";
```

Codeigniter default routes should work for `http://YOUR_SITE/new_account/step1` cause you have a controller file called `step1.php` inside the folder `new_account`. Also check that the name of the class of your controller inside `step1.php` is `Step1`

Comment: Thank you. I commented `$route['new_account/(:any)'] = "new_account";` and when I went to `site_name/new_account/step1`, it redirected to a 404 message. I used a link to get to `step1`. I also have controllers like `personal_info.php` with a class name of `Personal_info`. What do you think?

Comment: I have revised your routes.php again, comment this line: $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/show_page/$1'; too and try again.